# Apply wrapper to css block

Tags: html, css, sass

I have several CSS styles that I am overriding on a specific page.  I have a wrapper div around the entire thing, so I was hoping I could add the modified styles to my stylesheet without having to append the wrapper div to each style.

Something like this...

```
#myWrapper {

     #existingStyleImOverriding { width:100%; etc; }
     ...more styles....

}
```

That way the "modified" styles only apply if the myWrapper div is around the content.  Anyway to do that without having to change each style like...

```
#myWrapper #existingStyleImOverriding { width:100%; etc; }
....
```

Comment: If you want every element within the wrapper with the new ID to have a width of 100% you could add: #myWrapper * {width: 100%;}

Comment: @SeanHenderson - thank you for the suggestion, but the width was just an example my styles are much more complex and unique than that.  I think I'm going to just have to either create a separate sheet for this specific page or prepend everything i want overridden with #myWrapper

Comment: That is invalid CSS in the first example. Are you using SASS or something? Add that tag.

Comment: If you are able to change the html, you could use some kind of modifier class to perform your overrides.  eg  `.w100 { width:100%; }`. I would need to see more code to understand what you are going for, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to make use of the nesting capability of [sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

It would let you write this:

```
#myWrapper {
  #override1 { width:100%; }
  #override2 { width:100%; }
  #override3 { width:100%; }
  #override4 { width:100%; }
}
```

and then it would compile it to this:

```
#myWrapper #override1 {
  width: 100%;
}
#myWrapper #override2 {
  width: 100%;
}
#myWrapper #override3 {
  width: 100%;
}
#myWrapper #override4 {
  width: 100%;
}
```